# Syfmony: upload files with dropzone

Tags: symfony, dropzone.js, vichuploaderbundle, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm developing a king of simple CMS, with Symfony 4.1.

Regarding my question, we have 2 entities:

- Post Entity:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Entity;

  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
   */
  class Post extends BaseEntity
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Id()
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
       * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="text")
       */
      private $content;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
       */
      private $status;

      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="posts")
       */
      private $categories;

      /**
       * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Picture", mappedBy="post", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
       */
      private $pictures;

      /**
       * @Assert\All({@Assert\Image(mimeTypes="image/jpeg")})
       *
       */
      private $pictureFiles;

      /**
       * Post constructor.
       */
      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
          $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
      }

      /**
       * @return int|null
       */
      public function getId(): ?int
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      /**
       * @return null|string
       */
      public function getContent(): ?string
      {
          return $this->content;
      }

      /**
       * @param string $content
       * @return Post
       */
      public function setContent(string $content): self
      {
          $this->content = $content;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return bool|null
       */
      public function getStatus(): ?bool
      {
          return $this->status;
      }

      /**
       * @param bool $status
       * @return Post
       */
      public function setStatus(bool $status): self
      {
          $this->status = $status;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return Collection|Category[]
       */
      public function getCategories(): Collection
      {
          return $this->categories;
      }

      /**
       * @param Category $category
       * @return Post
       */
      public function addCategory(Category $category): self
      {
          if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
              $this->categories[] = $category;
          }

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @param Category $category
       * @return Post
       */
      public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
      {
          if ($this->categories->contains($category)) {
              $this->categories->removeElement($category);
          }

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return Collection|Picture[]
       */
      public function getPictures(): Collection
      {
          return $this->pictures;
      }

      /**
       * @param Picture $picture
       * @return Post
       */
      public function addPicture(Picture $picture): self
      {
          if (!$this->pictures->contains($picture)) {

              $this->pictures[] = $picture;
              $picture->setPost($this);
          }

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @param Picture $picture
       * @return Post
       */
      public function removePicture(Picture $picture): self
      {
          if ($this->pictures->contains($picture)) {

              $this->pictures->removeElement($picture);

              if ($picture->getPost() === $this) {
                  $picture->setPost(null);
              }
          }

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return mixed
       */
      public function getPictureFiles()
      {
          return $this->pictureFiles;
      }

      /**
       * @param $pictureFiles
       * @return Post
       */
      public function setPictureFiles($pictureFiles): self
      {
          foreach ($pictureFiles as $pictureFile) {

              /** @var Picture $picture */
              $picture = new Picture();

              $picture->setImageFile($pictureFile);
              $this->addPicture($picture);
          }

          $this->pictureFiles = $pictureFiles;

          return $this;
      }
  }
  ```
- Picture Entity:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PictureRepository")
   */
  class Picture
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Id()
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
       * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @var File|null
       * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes="image/jpeg")
       */
      private $imageFile;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
       */
      private $filename;

      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="pictures")
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
       */
      private $post;

      /**
       * @return int|null
       */
      public function getId(): ?int
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      /**
       * @return File|null
       */
      public function getImageFile(): ? File
      {
          return $this->imageFile;
      }

      /**
       * @param File|null $imageFile
       * @return Picture
       */
      public function setImageFile(? File $imageFile): self
      {
          $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return string|null
       */
      public function getFilename(): ?string
      {
          return $this->filename;
      }

      /**
       * @param string $filename
       * @return Picture
       */
      public function setFilename(string $filename): self
      {
          $this->filename = $filename;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * @return Post|null
       */
      public function getPost(): ?Post
      {
          return $this->post;
      }

      /**
       * @param Post|null $post
       * @return Picture
       */
      public function setPost(?Post $post): self
      {
          $this->post = $post;

          return $this;
      }
  }
  ```

So for adding a Post, I have a **PostType**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Post;
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class PostType
 * @package App\Form
 */
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('content', CKEditorType::class)
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class'        => Category::class,
                    'required'     => true,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple'     => true,
                ]
            )
            ->add('pictureFiles', FileType::class,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'label'    => 'Add files...',
                    'attr' =>
                        [
                            'action' => '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/posts'
                        ]
                ]
            )
            ->add('status')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The view corresponding to that form:

```
{% form_theme form '/admin/form/switch_btn_layout.html.twig' %}

{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
            {{ form_row(form.status) }}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 dropzone" id="postDropzone">
            {{ form_row(form.pictureFiles, {'attr': {'class': 'dropzone'}} ) }}

            <div class="dropzone-previews" style="border: 1px solid red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.content) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.status) }}
    </div>

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="postSubmit">
        {{ button_label|default('Save') }}
    </button>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

As you can see, the "input" for files as the dropzone css class.
Indeed, my project include the oneup_uploader bundle, for dropzone.

Here the configuration for oneup_uploader:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        # This is a mapping example, remove it and create your own mappings.
        post_image:
            frontend: dropzone
            namer: oneup_uploader.namer.uniqid
            storage:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/posts'
```

And my script for Dropzone:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var postDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {

    url: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/posts',
    // url: 'file/post',
    maxFiles: 10,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,

});

postDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {

    file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
        postDropzone.removeFile(file);
    })
});
```

The issue for me is:

- no file is save in the folder
- the Post entity is save in my DB, but nothing is save for Pictures.

I also tried to not use OneUploaderBundle, and use VichUploader: the saving part in DB is perfect, but I can't link it to dropzone.

Some help guys ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be useful for new visitors.
You can use a library that extends Symfony Form and adds a new type [DropzneType](https://github.com/emr-dev/symfony-dropzone).

1.Install the library

```
composer require emrdev/symfony-dropzone
```

This way you will have a new form type DropzoneType

2.Use the type in your form like this

```
public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{ 

    // userFiles is OneToMany
    $builder->add('userFiles', DropzoneType::class, [
        'class' => File::class,
        'maxFiles' => 6,
        'uploadHandler'=>'uploadHandler',  // route name
        'removeHandler'=> 'removeHandler'// route name
   ]);
}
```

Change the uploadHandler and removeHandler options to your endpoints

3.Route uploadHandler/removeHandler might look something like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/uploadhandler", name="uploadHandler")
 */
public function uploadhandler(Request $request, ImageUploader $uploader) { 
    $doc = $uploader->upload($request->files->get('file'));  
    $file = new File(); 
    $file->setSrc($doc['src']);
    ...

    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($file);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    return new JsonResponse($file);
}


/**
 * @Route("/removeHandler/{id}", name="removeHandler")
 */
public function removeHandler(Request $request,File $file = null) {
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($file);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    return new JsonResponse(true);
}
```

> note that uploadhandler should return a File object

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `upload url` instead of `upload directory`

generate url in twig - `{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('post_image') }}`

```
var postDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone', {
    url: '{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('post_image') }}',
    // url: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/posts',
    // url: 'file/post',
    maxFiles: 10,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,

});
```